# Script for delayed program start

Tags: vbscript

i have written following vbScript file to make several programs autostart with delay:

```
'Delay time 50 seconds
WScript.sleep 50000

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Google Trans
WshShell.Run "E:\prg\gDesktopTranslator_v1.0\gDesktopTranslator.exe"

 WScript.Sleep 2000

'Skype
cmd_1 =  chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" & chr(34)
cmd_2 = "/nosplash /minimized"
skype_cmd =  cmd_1 & " " & cmd_2

WshShell.Run   skype_cmd, 1, True

Set WshShell = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

But the problem is that after script executes, WScript file is still in memory :(
I supposed WScript will be closed by WScript.Quit
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Exec method instead of Run.

Example:

```
Dim WshShell, oExec
Set shShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("E:\prg\gDesktopTranslator_v1.0\gDesktopTranslator.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'W' missing in the Answer of YWE.
I cannot comment, because my reputations are too less...

Second line should be:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```